# How can we handle button click like event for entry box in gtk-rs?

Tags: rust, gtk3, gtk-rs

We can add a button click event in gtk-rs like this

```
let btn: Button = builder.get_object("button1").expect("Cant get button");
btn.connect_clicked(|_| {
        println!("Activated");
    });
```

like the above code how can I add similar click event for entry box such that when I press the mouse on the entry box it should print `pressed`. I tried this

```
let entry: Entry =  builder.get_object("box1").expect("Cant get box");
entry.connect_icon_press(|_, _, _| {
    println!("pressed");
});
```

The program is compiling without any error but when I clicked on the entry box I expected to see `pressed` in terminal but instead there is nothing.

Comment: [`connect_button_press_event`](https://gtk-rs.org/docs/gtk/trait.WidgetExt.html#tymethod.connect_button_press_event) and [`connect_button_release_event`](https://gtk-rs.org/docs/gtk/trait.WidgetExt.html#tymethod.connect_button_release_event) should work for any widget.

Comment: `connect_icon_press` is for pressing the activatable icon that can be embedded inside an entry.

Comment: Thank you, that worked, may I ask in gtk-rs why some times we have to return `Inhibit(true)` in some closures?

Comment: @Eka because signal emitter expects you to provide a return value. In `GSourceFunc` it shows whether function should be scheduled again, in events it allows you to stop or propagate event handling (look at `returns` section [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-button-press-event))